# fetching a string and erase duplicates

Tags: plsql

I have a cursor called cACLsonDistribution that I fetch into the variable called ACLs.
The cursor is populated with a list of emails and sometimes those emails are duplicated.

```
LOOP
      FETCH cACLsonDistribution INTO ACLs;
      EXIT WHEN cACLsonDistribution%NOTFOUND;
         ACLsonDistribution := ACLsonDistribution || ','|| ACLs.ENGINEER_EMAIL;

          END LOOP;
```

This returns a string like this:

> ,bernardo.t@example.com,bernardo.t@example.com,felipe.t@example.com,jose.t@example.com

As you can see there 2 duplicates emails there. Sometimes there are 3 duplicates emails. What I would like to return the string without the duplicates. Like this:

> ,bernardo.t@example.com,felipe.t@example.com,jose.t@example.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple illustration. Hope this helps.

```
SET SQLBL ON;
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  PLST SYS_REFCURSOR;
  AV      VARCHAR2(100);
  LV_VAR  VARCHAR2(100);
  VAR_TAB VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  OPEN PLST FOR SELECT 'avrajit.roy@abc.com' nm FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'avrajit.roy@abc.com' nm FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'shubhojit.roy@abc.com' nm FROM DUAL;
  LOOP
    FETCH plst INTO AV;
    EXIT
  WHEN PLST%NOTFOUND;
    --  NULL;
    lv_var:=lv_var||','||av;
  END LOOP;
  --  close
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(LV_VAR,2,LENGTH(LV_VAR)));
  SELECT WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(a.txt)
  INTO var_tab
  FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTR(LV_VAR,2,LENGTH(LV_VAR)),'[^,]+', 1, level)) txt
    FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY regexp_substr(SUBSTR(LV_VAR,2,LENGTH(LV_VAR)), '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
    )a;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_tab);
END;

----------------------------------OUTPUT----------------------------------------

avrajit.roy@abc.com,shubhojit.roy@abc.com

----------------------------------OUTPUT----------------------------------------
```

Comment: SELECT WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(a.txt) INTO var_tab FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTR(LV_VAR,2,LENGTH(LV_VAR)),'[^,]+', 1, level)) txt FROM DUAL CONNECT BY regexp_substr(SUBSTR(LV_VAR,2,LENGTH(LV_VAR)), '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL )a; just try to use this part

Comment: Hi buddy, I'm fetching the cursor into a variable and then I'm concatenating the emails into the variable Discontinuation. Applying your code, do I have to replace the a.txt by the variable Discontinuation? what would you suggest?

    OPEN cDiscontinuation;
    Discontinuation :='';
    Loop
    FETCH cDiscontinuation INTO DOD;
     EXIT WHEN cDiscontinuation%NOTFOUND;
             Discontinuation := Discontinuation || ','|| DOD.ENGINEER_EMAIL;
    END LOOP;

Comment: Just replace lv_var with ACLsonDistribution and try. Hope it helps

Comment: After end loop.  Put the SELECT INTO clause with lv_var replaced with ACLsonDistribution

Comment: Heey... Discontinuation is the same as ACLsonDistribution.... I did it like this but had these error about the right parenthesis. It seems to be ook with that... please correct me.

Comment: Loop
    FETCH cDiscontinuation INTO DOD;
     EXIT WHEN cDiscontinuation%NOTFOUND;
             Discontinuation := Discontinuation || ','|| DOD.ENGINEER_EMAIL;
    SELECT WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(a.txt) INTO var_tab FROM (SELECT   DISTINCT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Discontinuation,2,LENGTH(Discontinuation)),'[^,]+', 1, level)) txt 
             FROM DUAL CONNECT BY regexp_substr(SUBSTR(Discontinuation,2,LENGTH(Discontinuation)), '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
    END LOOP;
    SELECT INTO clause with Discontinuation;

Comment: I have this error: 
ORA-06550: line 47, column 130:
PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06550: line 46, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 49, column 8:
PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06550: line 49, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


2.         
3.     l_body varchar2(5000);
4.     l_body_html varchar2(5000);
5.     l_workspace_id number;
6.     DiscontinuationEmail varchar2(5000);